# Хитрый способ форматирования кода ("контроль версий" с помощью символа ';')

Tags: c++, c, контроль-версий, форматирование

Суть:

```
int foo()//                              ;
{                                        ;  
    int a                                ;
    float b                              ; //В правой части старые 
    typedef int testing                  ; //полезные комментарии
    std::cout << "Ho-ho-ho"              ;
    a=0                                  ;
    b=1.0f                               ;
    if (a==b)//                          ;
    {                                    ;
        std::cout <<"Yet another caption";
        std::cout <<"Hi-hi-hi"           ;
        bar()                            ;
                                         ;
    }                                    ;
    using namespace std                  ;
    for (int i =0;i<10;i++)//            ;
    {                                    ;
                                         ;
        std::cout <<"Hello, world!"      ;
        std::cout <<"Yet another line"   ;
    }                                    ;
    return 0                             ;
                                         ;
}                                        ;
```

Кто-то что-то решил изменить:

```
int foo()//                              ;
{                                        ;  
    int a                                ;
    float b                              ; //В правой части старые 
    typedef int testing                  ; //полезные комментарии
    std::cout << "Ho-ho-ho"              ;
    a=0                                  ;
    b=1.0f                               ;
    if (a==b)//                          ;
    {                                    ;
        std::cout <<"Yet another caption";
        std::cout <<"Hi-hi-hi"           ;
        bar()                            ;
                                         ;
    }                                    ;
    double c;
    //Слева комментарии требующие
    //проверки. Зачем здесь с????
    using namespace std                  ;
    for (int i =0;i<10;i++)//            ;
    {                                    ;
                                         ;
        std::cout <<"Hello, world!"      ;
        std::cout <<"Yet another line"   ;
    }                                    ;
    return 6666                            ;
                                         ;
}                                        ;
```

Легко определили по линии из точек с запятой место в котором произошло изменение. Подумали над ним. Если согласились с изменениями восстановили линию из точек с запятой. Также можно понять была ли вставлена новая строчка или поменяли уже написанную. По разному цвету точек с запятой можно быстро найти управляющие конструкции/макросы/заголовки функций.

Подводные камни:

- Выравнивать надо пробелами, а не табуляцией, иначе не видно мелких изменений меньше разрмера табуляции.
- Если изменение не меняет длину строки нужно добавлять после него пару пробелов.
- Длинные строчки все портят.
- Без плагина к текстовому редактору, который выравнивает автоматически этот способ требует слишком много времени.

Вот этим [плагином](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd) уже можно вытворять такое(правда он выравнивает табуляцией и не добавляет значок комментария).

Вчера в голову пришла эта идея когда смотрел разные стили форматирования, никогда раньше не встречал такого в связи с этим вопрос кто что думает по поводу полезности/бесполезности этого трюка? Я пока не могу трезво оценить окупает ли его использование время затраченное на форматирование.

Comment: А точка с запятой уже считается комментарием?

Comment: Неплохая альтернатива `git'у`. Остается только прикрутить мерджи - конфликты, например, можно помечать с помощью `;;;`

Comment: не будет работать к примеру в питоне.

Думаю это для тех, кто не хочет работать и придумывает всякие сложности.

Мое мнение - толку ноль, проблем - вагон и тележка. Плюс размер файла больше (хотя сейчас прибегут те, кто будет говорить, что гигабайты стоят копейки все такое).

Comment: @igumnov, у Вас один и тот же файл (кода программы) много людей правят?

Мне кажется, это неправильный подход.

Comment: Зависит от языка. Плюс табами не вариант потому как ширина таба может зависеть от редактора, а пробелами - рука устанет клацать, да и следить после каждой новой строчки нужно правильно ли сделал отступ. А упомянутый плагин годен только для определенной среды. А так идея интересная конечно. В принципе можно представить себе ситуацию когда пригодится.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. Также пока склоняюсь к бесполезности фичи.

Comment: Пробелы vs табы? Т.е. у вас в коде используются как табы, так и пробелы? Мне вас жаль.

А по поводу системы - если бы я попал в команду где ползуются таким подходом, то я бы или ушел сразу, или дал бы по щщам тому кто это придумал :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Я считаю, не нужно искусственным применением спец. форматирования пытаться выполнить работу системы контроля версий и IDE.

Код выглядит ненатурально (а это означает, что разработчик потратит дополнительное время, чтобы понять его); все участники проекта должны будут использовать одну и ту же среду и один и тот же плагин к ней. Такой синтаксис требует комментариев в неожиданных местах; автоматическое форматирование текста невозможно. Кроме того, строка наподобие

```
using namespace std                  ;
```

вызывает ощущение неправильности: точка с запятой выглядит не как конец оператора, а как часть "визуального мусора" справа.
Кроме того, такой стиль не решает проблему: если вы меняете "0" на "1", ряд из ";" визуально не поменяется.

Теперь о решении проблем: для обзора сделанных изменений подойдёт любая система контроля версий. Современные редакторы, начиная с vi / Far+Colorer и заканчивая Visual Studio, умеют правильно и конфигурируемо раскрашивать исходники. Поэтому, мне кажется, проблемы на самом деле и нет.

---

Кроме того, такой метод форматирования может привести к сложным, практически неотлавливаемым ошибкам:

```
if (cond)                            ;
{                                    ;
    doSomething()                    ;
}                                    ;
```

-- этот код компилируется, но работает, скорее всего, не так, как задумывал программист.

Comment: Проблему с `;` можно решить. Одна комма - закрывает конструкцию языка, вторая - делает линию выравнивания. Но при этом составной оператор на две строчки не напишешь =( По крайней мере без того, чтобы `;` не закомментировать. В общем - действительно, много мороки для поддержания системы в работоспособном варианте.

Comment: @gecube: угу, слишком много мороки, как мне кажется.